# mongodb c++ driver- error: “mongo::client” has not been declared

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, raspberry-pi, scons

i got an error when trying to test an example after installing mongodb , boost and mongodb-cxx driver
(the example use the c++ driver for mongodb)

The version of the driver i am trying to build (branch or tag).

> legacy

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
git checkout legacy
```

Host OS, version, and architecture.

```
Raspbian wheezy : Linux version 3.18.14-v7+ (root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140106 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.01 - Linaro GCC 2013.11) )
```

C++ Compiler and version.

```
g++/gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3
```

Boost version.

```
Examples: boost 1.58.0
```

How boost was built or installed.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

```
 ./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install --prefix=PREFIX
```

The complete SCons invocation.

```
scons
```

I haven't done any configure ...

i am trying to run this file with

> g++  -I/opt/mongo/include/ -I/opt/mongo/include/mongo
>   -I/home/pi/boost_1_58_0/PREFIX/include -L/home/pi/boost_1_58_0/PREFIX/lib -L/opt/mongo/lib/ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial

-file tutorial.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "/opt/mongo/include/mongo/client/dbclient.h" // for the driver

void run() {
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
    mongo::client::initialize();
    try {
        run();
        std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
    } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
        std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

results - error:

> tutorial.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: tutorial.cpp:12:12: error:
>   ‘mongo::client’ has not been declared

any hint please , thanks ?

Comment: Do you have any headers in /opt/mongo/include/?

Comment: @Nipheris  No but in headers in dbclient.h have some relative path like "mongo" wish is a subfolder of /opt/mongo/include/ , however removing -I/opt/mongo/include/  solved the error but i'm getting now fatal error: mongo/util/signal_handlers.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes I am facing the same problem.